# How to have a custom font hook acessible from pages

Tags: react-native, expo

I have got back into React Native after a few years and wanted to get a custom font. I tried looking through the documentation but they only have a way how to do it on the page itself and you can't use styles. They mentioned

`Font.LoadAsync()`

But that too is not working for me as I am using a function rather than a class.

I looked into the code I did a few years back and found out that the way I did this was this:

```
import * as Font from "expo-font";
 
export default useFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'CantoraOne': require('../assets/fonts/CantoraOne-Regular.ttf'),
  });
```

```
export default function Dice() {

    const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

    const LoadFonts = async () => {
        await useFonts();
    };

    if (!IsReady) {
        return (
            <AppLoading
                startAsync={LoadFonts}
                onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
                onError={() => { }}
            />
        );
    }



    return (
<Text style={styles.text}>Some text</Text>
    )
}




const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontFamily: 'CantoraOne',
        fontSize: 50,
    },
})
```

This worked but when I tried doing the same workaround now. I found out that "App Loading" is deprecated and should not be used. I don't know of any other way how to do it and I feel lost.

How can I make a central place from which I can import a custom font into every page on my project without needing to write "Font.LoadAsync()" into every page?

Answer (score 0):

AppLoading is deprecated because the functionality is easily created on your own. Check out the usage recommended in the current docs:

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/#usage

1. Keep loading state at the root level to track whether the fonts are loaded, starting with true
2. Load the fonts in a useEffect, set loading to false when done
3. Return a loading indicator while the fonts are unloaded and the app when they are done

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned, I have looked through the documentation and this does not solve the problem. Not only can you not style with Stylesheet this way, I also don't have the font in a separate file

Comment: The code in the docs works.  If you post what you have tried, we can help.

Comment: I did, the code I posted is in two files. I want a sort of global hook to load the fonts and in the page itself I want to have as least code possible to load fonts and to be able to use them in a stylesheet

Comment: I'm not clear on your question.  Your code works, right?  It's just that AppLoading is deprecated?  Why do you need a global hook?  The "right" way to do this is how you have it, in the initial App.js.